# MySQL connector c++ linux

Tags: c++, mysql, boost

I am trying use the mysql connector in c++ in ubuntu.

It appears that it requires the boost library. I did not want to bring in the boost library as it is large and this is running on a somewhat memory limited embedded platform. is there any way to include only parts of the boost library, and if so, how would I find out which parts to make mysql run?

Comment: No connector should need boost. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Boost is not a library, it is a collection of libraries. Use only the libraries you need and the size of the overall collection of libraries is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [MySQL Connector for C++](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/1.1.htm) on Linux (select "Linux - Generic" in the drop-down box).  It does not require Boost.  You may want to try this one in lieu of the one you're using.

Comment: It's not one of the architectures supported directly on the website.  However, it is released as GPL, so you can download the source and compile it for ARM.